# Will supplied iPad icons be displayed, even if the application is built only for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

For a non-universal iPhone app, if I include the iPad icons (50X50, 72X72), will the iPad display those icons?

Answer (score 3):

From the Apple docs:

> ### Providing Application Icons for iPad
>
> An iPad application supports the following icon sizes:
>
> - A 72 x 72 pixel for the main application icon.
> - A 50 x 50 pixel icon for displaying with Spotlight search results.
> - A 29 x 29 pixel icon for the application’s Settings bundle, if present.
>
> For information about how to specify these icons in your application bundle, see the discussion of application icons in “Build-Time Configuration Details” in iOS Application Programming Guide.

You'll find details on page 92 of the *iOS Application Programming Guide*.

And yes. If available, iPad will display the iPad-designated icons - even if the app is non-universal (that is, an iPhone app).

Comment: Would be nice of you would accept the answer by clicking the "√" on the left. :)

Answer (score 0):

Non Universal means that your build target is iphone right ? if so , then IPAD will display those icons ..